# Missing Required Architecture arm in file

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, cfnetwork

When I compile my application, I get an error stating that

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork, missing required architecture arm in file.
```

I have checked all the frameworks, and they all point to the iPhone 3.0 SDK Frameworks...

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you used any third party frameworks, or just apple ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I finally solved the problem. The solution was to set the "Framework Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" to "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework"

I removed the other values that were there and it seems to work. I am using more frameworks but only CFNetwork seems to be problematic (until now :) ).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That path is to one of your Mac's frameworks, which shouldn't be anywhere near your iPhone app.

Go to Targets in your Project's sidebar and check what's listed under "Link Binary with Libraries". None of them should point anywhere else but the SDK frameworks. If you don't find anything wrong there, have a look in the Build Results panel, preferably after doing a Clean. That should give you some clues as to what's happening.